# How do I create a help function for a module created by me in PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module

My code is:

```py
import os

#This function renames the given file!
def rename(file_name, new_name):
     file_name = str(file_name)
     a = os.rename(file_name, new_name)
     return a
```

Now When I run my code in IDLE:

```py
>>> help(rename)
Help on function rename in module __main__:

rename(file_name, new_name)
    #This function renames the given file!

>>>
```

It returns like this!
If Code Like this:

```py
import os

#This function renames the given file!
def rename(file_name, new_name):
    #In the file_name you have to give the file's name with extention!
    #In the new_name you have to give the new file's name with extention!
     file_name = str(file_name)
     a = os.rename(file_name, new_name)
     return a
```

And use help function in IDLE:

```py
>>> help(rename)
Help on function rename in module __main__:

rename(file_name, new_name)
    #This function renames the given file!

>>>
```

It returns the same!
Is there and way to print all the comments
when i use:

```py
>>>help(rename)
Help on function rename in module __main__:

rename(file_name, new_name)
    #This function renames the given file!
    #In the file_name you have to give the file's name with extention!
    #In the new_name you have to give the new file's name with extention!
```

Like this?

Comment: The response from `help(whatever)` should not be changed when run in IDLE instead of standard interative Python.  As the answer say, it depends on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use docstrings.
for example:

```
def rename(file_name, new_name):
    '''
    In the file_name you have to give the file's name with extention!
    In the new_name you have to give the new file's name with extention!
    '''
file_name = str(file_name)
    a = os.rename(file_name, new_name)
    return a
```

so when you call help(rename), you should get:

```
Help on function rename in module __main__:

rename(file_name, new_name)
    In the file_name you have to give the file's name with extention!
    In the new_name you have to give the new file's name with extention!
```

Comment: Your Welcome! An upvote will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#:%7E:text=A%20docstring%20is%20a%20string,module%20should%20also%20have%20docstrings.). You use """ """ format to give your function a documentation that can be viewed with the help function.